# composite glass

Tags: compositing-nodes, glass, world

I'm trying to composite an image with glass but I don't know if there is a workable solution for the scenario I have in mind. 
The set up consists of two parts:  
the first in itself is a composite of the following: 
A scene of 4 figures with their own lighting composited with a world scene.  
the second part is a water glass standing on a low wall. 
Ideally I would want the glass lighting to be a combination of the world lighting and a point light, but to display the right (or close enough) refractions.
My best shot so far is this: 
  
[image]

The other scenes are: 
[image] 
 
[image] 
[image]

Any help making this better is appreciated! will try to upload a file but my internet is bad atm.

Comment: Why do use different scenes to do this instead of one? If the reason is only to isolate lights to specific objects, we have light linking to do that.

Comment: yes, only to isolate different light sources to different objects. Never heard of light linking during my research. will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: This 1min long video could be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=excz9dfRycQ

Comment: thank you, it's a good solution!